# Paginação em laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, paginação

Estou realizando uma paginação dos dados da seguinte forma:

Controller:

```
$brands = $this->brand::where('id', $filter_id)->paginate($this->total_page);
```

View:

```
{{ $brands->appends(['id' => isset($filter_id) ? $filter_id : ''])->links() }}
```

Este é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de deixar parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sabem onde posso mudar esse numero de "links" deixando menor o intervalo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para customizar a páginação, devemos mexer um pouco na estrutura do laravel,

Temos que acessar o arquivo do laravel

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/UrlWindow.php
```

deixe seus métodos conforme os seguintes:

```
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->paginator->getUrlRange(1, 1);
}

public function getFinish()
    {
        return $this->paginator->getUrlRange(
            $this->lastPage(),
            $this->lastPage()
        );
    }
public function getAdjacentUrlRange($onEachSide)
    {
        return $this->paginator->getUrlRange(
            $this->currentPage() - 1,
            $this->currentPage() + 1
        );
    }
protected function getSliderTooCloseToEnding($window)
    {
        $last = $this->paginator->getUrlRange(
            $this->lastPage() - (2),
            $this->lastPage()
        );

        return [
            'first' => $this->getStart(),
            'slider' => null,
            'last' => $last,
        ];
    }

protected function getSliderTooCloseToBeginning($window)
    {
        return [
            'first' => $this->paginator->getUrlRange(1, 3),
            'slider' => null,
            'last' => $this->getFinish(),
        ];
    }
```

E pronto, a mágica ta feita!!!

Comment: Caso fique com alguma duvida ou queria saber mais sobre esses métodos me coloco a disposição para poder ajudar.

Comment: muito bem, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.